Total space of the normal bundle
I'm studying the total space of the normal vector bundle of a manifold $M$ differentiable embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, defined by:
$N = \{(q,v) | q \in M, \text{ vperpendicular to M at q}\} \subset M \times \mathbb{R}^n$
Obv it is a n-manifold, but the book that I'm readind says that N is differentiable embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. I'm not sure about this last sentence, anyone can help?

Proving local triviality takes some work; I don’t see why it’s obvious. But it is obvious that this set is a subset of $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$.

It's obv becaue the total space of the normal bundle it's seen as $T\mathbb{R}^n|i(M) / TM$ where $i$ it's the inclusion of M in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's obvius that this set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, but my professor told me to demonstrate the differentiable embedding thinking about the fact that the fiber $N_p$ is the ortogonal complement of $T_pM$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I don't understand why

If $$F: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,$$ is the inclusion map, then there is a natural embedding $$ F^T_\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow T_*\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n. $$ The normal and tangent bundles are subbundles and therefore submanifolds of $F^T_\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm not sure of understand what you say. We have the embedding of M in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's tangent map (that you call $F^$ I assume), is F: $T_pM \rightarrow T_p\mathbb{R}^n$, then how this implies the embedding of N in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

No. $F^$ is not a map. $F$ is a map, and $F^T_\mathbb{R}^n$ is the notation used for what is called the pullback bundle of $T_\mathbb{R}^n$ via the map $F$.

Before I post an answer, could you revise your question to make it more precisely stated? For example, $M$ is not just a manifold. It is assumed to be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Note that there is a canonical spitting of the tangent bundle of $\R^n$,
$$ T_*\R^n = \R^n\times\R^n. $$
Let $F: M \rightarrow \R^n$ be an embedding. The Jacobian (i.e, pushforward) of $F$ defines for each $x \in M$ a linear embedding
$$ \partial F(x): T_xM \rightarrow T_{F(x)}\R^n = \R^n. $$
In particular, $\partial F(x)T_xM$ is a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\R^n$. By definition, the fiber of the normal bundle at $x$ is the $(n-k)$-dimensional orthogonal complement of $\partial F(x)T_xM\subset \R^n$. Therefore, $N_xM \subset \R^n$ is a $(n-k)$-dimensional linear subspace. You then have the map
\begin{align*} N_*M &\rightarrow \R^n\times\R^n\\
(x,v) &\mapsto (F(x),v),
\end{align*}
which is easily shown to be an embedding.
